# How can I do select of all user referral id?

Tags: php

How can I do select of all user referral?

```
| id    |            user_id |    friend_id |
|-------|--------------------|--------------|
| 1     |                1   |          2   |
| 2     |                2   |          3   |
| 3     |                3   |          4   |
| 4     |                10  |          15  |
```

So in the above instance user 1 would have a referral trail of 3 because the person they referred, referred someone and then the person they referred referred someone else...

It might be better to do it as a php function but I'm struggling to get my head around it?

Below is my CODE

```
public function has_child($referee_referees){
        $this->db->select("user_account_phone");
        $this->db->where('referee_phone_number', $referee_referees);

        $query = $this->db->get('account');

        if($query->num_rows() == 0) {

            return FALSE;

        }

        return TRUE;
    }



    public function get_referee_referee_details($user_account_phone){
            $this->db->select('user_account_phone');
            $this->db->where('referee_phone_number', $product_phone_number);
            $query = $this->db->get('account');

            foreach($query->result() as $rows){
                $child_ids[$rows->user_account_phone] = $rows->user_account_phone;
                $referee_referees = $rows->user_account_phone;

                if($this->has_child($referee_referees)){
                    $child_ids[$rows->user_account_phone] = $this->get_referee_referee_details($rows->user_account_phone);  
                }

                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($child_ids);
                echo "</pre>";


                return $child_ids;

            }


        // return $child_ids;
    }
```

Comment: Is that a database? Are you using MySQL? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show your code what have you tried.

Comment: select * from referral

Comment: iam using MYSQL

Comment: you should define your code first before asking others to code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the data in memory(which is problematic for a big table)

```
$users = array(
    array("id" => 1, "user_id" => 1 , "friend_id" => 2,),
    array("id" => 2, "user_id" => 2 , "friend_id" => 3,),
    array("id" => 3, "user_id" => 3 , "friend_id" => 4,),
    array("id" => 4, "user_id" => 10, "friend_id" => 15,),
);

function getRefferrals(&$users, $userId)
{
    $referrals = 1;

    foreach($users as $user) {
        if($user["user_id"] == $userId) {
            $referrals += getRefferrals($users, $user["friend_id"]);
        }
    }

    return $referrals;
}

$referrals = getRefferrals($users, 1) - 1;
var_dump($referrals);
```

If you do not have the data in memory you could check if the user has "friend_id" and if it exists in the table

Comment: tHANK YOU, IAM USING CODEIGNITER, IAM FINDING WAYS TO GET IT WORK OUT. WILL LET YOU KNOW WHEN IT DOES. YOU ARE SUCH A GREAT PERSON

Comment: Hello Katona.abel Thanks so much it works. Iam very grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write some code to iterate over results.

This code is very rough and doesn't work for users that have referred more than one person.

```
function get_referral_count($userId) {
    $count = 0;
    // Just an example, you should escape this query!
    while ($res = // SELECT * FROM user_referral where user_id = $userId;) 
    {
        $userId = $friendId;
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question

i tried shortest code for you

This will work - (you can test it with different data)

**select friend_id from demo where user_id =1 OR user_id IN(select friend_id from demo)**

Comment: dont forget to change your table name on that ... its demo in my query ...you can change that